# How can I resolve the error "Could not load file or assembly: Microsoft.IdentityModel" during configuration?

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint

Do you know what I have to do? I checked the Internet but I did not find good explanation of this problem. I'm not able to configure SharePoint in Windows 7.

[image: First error]

Now I get this error

[image: Second error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to install the [Windows Identity Foundation Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=eb9c345f-e830-40b8-a5fe-ae7a864c4d76&displaylang=en) on your machine.

Comment: I make this but I get now new error. Look my post.

Comment: Google tells me that you're missing the chart control: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422

Comment: thanks but for this last picture I find solution now is ok :) One more time thanks for help.

Comment: @RPD: If you have a *new* question/problem, please post a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

To setup SharePoint on Windows 7 you have to follow this guide to the point, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx

Comment: yes but I have got MSSQL 2012