# An error occurred during the installation of assembly

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, itunes, installer

[image]

I was trying to install itunes on windows 7, 64 bit, i got that error. the solution i found is to install VC++ runtime, i tried installing 2005 and 2008, got that same error, tried installing 2012, it said not a valid win32 program or something like that.

I tried installing .net framework 4.5, didn't fix it. I saw this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/465146/how-can-i-resolve-the-error-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-identity). I see nothing in the `Turn Windows features on or off` section and i tried installing without .net framework and with it, no difference, the presence or absence of the framework doesn't make any difference, the laptop didn't have .net framework before, i got this error, installed it to see what happens, the error is still the same.

Another solution is to use [Microsoft fix it](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;946414), but didn't fix it :)

Note that earlier today i had [this problem](https://superuser.com/questions/627192/windows-installer-service-could-not-be-started) on the same laptop, fixed that, now i have this, maybe they are related, i don't know.

I see no such thing as `Windows Module Installer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means `ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED`

```
C:\Users\André>err 0x80070422
# as an HRESULT: Severity: FAILURE (1), FACILITY_WIN32 (0x7), Code 0x422
# for hex 0x422 / decimal 1058
  ERROR_SERVICE_DISABLED                                         winerror.h
# The service cannot be started, either because it is
# disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated
# with it.
# 1 matches found for "0x80070422"
```

start `services.msc` and make sure the service `Windows Modules Installer` is NOT disabled.

Comment: i forgot to mention, i saw that solution, but there's no such thing as `Windows Module Installer`

Comment: the name is **Windows Modules Installer**: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/superuser/Windows_Modules_Installer.png